# Laravel 5.2 - How to run shell command via Modal / Controller

Tags: php, linux, laravel-5

How i can run shell command via a Model or Controller. Not through Artisan command or $schedule.

And also how i can run a sudo command?

I have try the next options. Nothing works:

1:

```
$process = new Process('sudo /usr/bin/touch /var/www/html/Poptin test2.html');
                $process->run();
                // executes after the command finishes
                if (!$process->isSuccessful()) {
                    throw new ProcessFailedException($process);
                }
```

2:

```
shell_exec(escapeshellcmd('sudo /usr/bin/touch /var/www/html/Poptin test2.html));
```

3:

```
exec('sudo /usr/bin/touch /var/www/html/Poptin test2.html);
```

Help please!

Answer (score 4):

Have just tested running exec in Laravel 5.5 and it works. 
This is what i tried:

```
$test = exec('echo 123');
dd($test);
```

I know you are running 5.2, but it should be no different i terms of running this.

I can see that you have forgot an ending ' in the exec method and also the  shell_exec.

Instead of writing

```
exec('sudo /usr/bin/touch /var/www/html/Poptin test2.html);
```

You should write

```
exec('sudo /usr/bin/touch /var/www/html/Poptin test2.html');
```

Also make sure that the command you are trying to run works when running it in the shell directly.

Answer (score 2):

what you have done is correct but you have to do it like this 
for example 
shell_exec('sudo /usr/bin/touch /var/www/html/Poptin test2.html') give a try and one more thing using of shell_exec in controller is a bad practice.

Comment: So what is the alternative?